# xpath get all elements after element

Tags: html, xpath

I have this html

```
<td>
    <p> text <p>
    <p align="left"> some text <a href="">link</a> text and other staff </p>
    <p> text <p>
    <p> text <p>
    <p> text <p>
    <p> text <p>
</td>
```

How i can get all `<p>` after `<p align="left">` ?

I write this xpath for getting `<p align="left">`, but how i can select all `p` elements after it?

```
//td/p[@align="left"][last()]
```

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. There is nothing in your question that requires a specific language, using `xpath` and perhaps `html` is plenty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `//td/p[@align="left"][last()]/following-sibling::p`.

Comment: why need `[last()]` ?

Comment: Well Alexander had `[last()]` in his expression, presumably for a reason, so I did not not remove it. If the sample XML or HTML is as simple as shown in the post then it does not matter and is not needed, but perhaps the real sample has several `p` elements with the `align="left"` attribute.

Comment: Ok.. That actually forced me to produce another answer. Cool!

Comment: @ArupRakshit, because i have more then one elements `<p align="left">`. In the example i did not write full html that i have... i write only fragment.

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev You could write it in the post also. Your sample and code is a bit odd... Anyway.. you got answer, that's all!